# c# getting xml node that doesn't have close tag explicity

Tags: c#, .net, xml

this is my xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <SMS>
  <DeliveryDate>6/27/2015 3:00:00 PM</DeliveryDate> 
  <Status>DELIVRD</Status> 
  <Error /> 
  </SMS>
```

i want to know if the **error** node contains text or not

i tried this:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(responseMessage);
                string errorTagBody = doc.SelectSingleNode("ERROR").InnerText;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorTagBody))
```

but i got this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TestStatus.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

on this line:

```
string errorTagBody = doc.SelectSingleNode("ERROR").InnerText;
```

not that sometimes, the xml could be like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <SMS>
  <DeliveryDate>6/27/2015 3:00:00 PM</DeliveryDate> 
  <Error>Not formatted mobile number </ERROR>
  </SMS>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting it like this.

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(responseMessage);
    var node  = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Error");

    if (null != node && string.IsNullOrEmpty( node.InnerText ))
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not that it is a self closing tag. The problem is with your selection of the node.

What this says is get me an element called `ERROR` at the root of the document. There isn't one, so it returns null, you call `.InnerText` on null, you get a null ref exception.

```
string errorTagBody = doc.SelectSingleNode("ERROR").InnerText;
```

Instead of this, you can do this, meaning get me an `Error` element from any where in the document.

```
string errorTagBody = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Error").InnerText;
```

Or this, meaning get me the error element in the path SMS followed by Error.

```
string errorTagBody = doc.SelectSingleNode("SMS/Error").InnerText;
```

Also; case matters with XML. You can't close `Error` with `ERROR`, it's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [SelectSingleNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b(v=vs.110).aspx) with XPath syntax.

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("//Error").InnerText
```

Comment: I was jut to post it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

First XML is CASE SENSITIVE so if you are using a "Error" tag, search for "Error" instead of "ERROR"

Second, SelectSingleNode uses XPath, which is a way to reference xml nodes (you can find more about XPath by searching it on google). The correct XPath in your case is either "//Error" or "SMS/Error" (each one has a different way of working, again search on google about XPath to know which one do you want to use).

Run this code to see whats happening.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("[YUOR XML PATH]");
        XmlNode node1 = doc.SelectSingleNode("ERROR");
        XmlNode node2 = doc.SelectSingleNode("Error");
        XmlNode node3 = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ERROR");
        XmlNode node4 = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Error");
        XmlNode node5 = doc.SelectSingleNode("SMS/ERROR");
        XmlNode node6 = doc.SelectSingleNode("SMS/Error");

        if (node1 == null)
        { Console.WriteLine("Node 1 is null"); }

        if (node2 == null)
        { Console.WriteLine("Node 2 is null"); }


        if (node3 == null)
        { Console.WriteLine("Node 3 is null"); }


        if (node4 == null)
        { Console.WriteLine("Node 4 is null"); }


        if (node5 == null)
        { Console.WriteLine("Node 5 is null"); }


        if (node6 == null)
        { Console.WriteLine("Node 6 is null"); }
```